# 403 Forbidden stream but working

Tags: php, html

I get an error "430 Forbidden" when I click "TEST" link from here: http://ver.hol.es (It contains: `<a href="http://xxedge165.livesports.pw/live/la1/playlist.m3u8">TEST`)

However clicking the address bar and pressing ENTER, it works.

Is there any way to press ENTER automatically in order to play it? I tried with header via PHP but does not work.

Comment: I think you just need to add the download attribute.

Comment: The dowload attribute is not a solution, the stream needs to be played.

Comment: You should make that clear in your question. Your question says pressing enter on the address bar makes it work, which downloads it. So the natural assumption is that you want to be able to download it. Nowhere in your question does it mention the stream needs to be played.

Comment: Already edited. Sometimes it's not so easy to explain.

Answer (score 0):

Browser doesn't like to download the files automatically from the anchors due to the way you handle it in your server.

One option is to force the browser to navigate to your destination.

```
<a href='#' onClick="(function(){window.location='http://xxedge165.livesports.pw/live/la1/playlist.m3u8'})()">TEST
```

The other way is using the `download` attribute and tell the link to just download the file without navigating away.

```
<a href='http://xxedge165.livesports.pw/live/la1/playlist.m3u8' download>TEST
```

Comment: I forgot to disable the HLS Native playback... so the error 403 still present. :(

Comment: 403 has to be adjusted from your server. The question is about the frontend.

Answer (score -1):

> The 403 Forbidden error is an HTTP status code that means that accessing the page or resource you were trying to reach is absolutely forbidden for some reason.